# How do I count one list against another, in O(n*log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I am looking for a function that can efficiently count, for each element in one list, its occurrences in another list. It should return a sorted list of element/count tuples.  Here's the specification:

```
countList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, Integer)]
countList ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'x']
                               == [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('x', 0)]
length (countList xs ys) == length ys
```

A naive implementation would be:

```
countList xs = sort . map (id &&& length . (\ y -> filter (== y) xs))
```

This is `O(n^2)`. However, since we have `Ord a`, this could be made a bit faster using a better strategy. We might sort both lists first, and then compare them in a "ladder-climbing" fasion.

For example, here are the two lists sorted. If I were doing it imperatively, I would use two pointers pointing towards the first element in each list:

```
       i
       |
xs = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
ys = ['a', 'b', 'x']
       |
       j
```

Then increase `i` when `xs !! i == ys !! j`, meanwhile adding one to the counter at position `j`. When `i` encounters a new element, find it in `ys` by increasing `j`, and then repeat the previous step. This algorithm is `O(n*log(n))`.

But I can't find a way to achieve the same complexity in a purely functional way, nor did I find any existing function that can achieve what I want. How should I do this in Haskell?

Comment: This "ladder-climbing fasion" is very similar to the standard *merge* function. Look at the [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.3.0.1/docs/src/Data-List-Utils.html#merge) and modify to suit your needs.

Comment: The package [__data-ordlist__](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html) is devoted to operations on ordered lists - e.g. merge, minus, membership, insert, etc.

Comment: @trvoldermort: can `l2` contain duplicates? because — see my comment under Sam's answer — there could be performance implications. if it never contains duplicates, better to make this explicit and use a `Set` type or something.

Comment: @ErikAllik: That's a good concern. Technically it can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 2nd list does not have duplicates, and the 1st list is longer, you may *avoid sorting the first list* by using `Data.Map`. This will achieve an `n1 log n2` complexity:

```hs
import Data.Map (fromList, toList, adjust)

countList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countList l r = toList $ foldr (adjust (+1)) (fromList . zip r $ repeat 0) l
```

Comment: `adjust` is a function I have been defining over and over by myself for years now. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I think this accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
import Data.List (sort)

countList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countList l1 l2 = countList' (sort l1) (sort l2)
  where countList' _     []  = []
        countList' xs (y:ys) = let xs'   = dropWhile (<  y) xs
                                   (a,b) = span      (== y) xs'
                                in (y, length a) : countList' b ys

main = print $ countList ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'x']
```

Comment: in any case, +1, but the OP hasn't specified that `l2` will not contain duplicates; if it does, the recursive call needs to be `countList' xs' ys` not `countList' b ys`; then `span` can be replaced with `takeWhile`  — so that `countList ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'b', 'x', 'x']` would yield `[('a',1),('b',3),('b',0),('x',0),('x',0)]`. **otherwise**, the return value will have once `3` and then `0` for `b`, which will likely lead to bugs.